# ValueError in models.py

Tags: django, django-models

Here is my models.py file. When I try to migrate it gives me an error.

I changed Class name and it gives me an error. Now if I put even old name, it gives me the same error

```
from django.db import models
from tinymce.models import HTMLField



class BlockTags(models.Model):
    pass

class BlockTags_Text(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=300, verbose_name='Заголовок 1', null=True, blank=True)
    block = models.ForeignKey(BlockTags, related_name="text", verbose_name='Заголовок 1', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True,blank=True)
    number = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=0)







ValueError: The field content.BlockTags.text was declared with a lazy reference to 'content.blocktags_text', but app 'content' doesn't provide model 'blocktags_text'.
(venv) appledeMacBook-Pro:letbuycar apple$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`app 'content' doesn't provide model 'blocktags_text'.`

This means that django doesnt see a `blocktags_text` model in your `models.py`, try running `makemigrations` and then `migrate`, also try adding at least one field to your empty model.

Comment: tried to migrate, it gives `ValueError: Related model 'content.blocktags_text' cannot be resolved`

Comment: run makemigrations again then migrate

Comment: same thing, for makemigrations  this error `The field content.BlockTags.text was declared with a lazy reference to 'content.blocktags_text', but app 'content' doesn't provide model 'blocktags_text'.`

for migrate this `ValueError: Related model 'content.blocktags_text' cannot be resolved`

Comment: try deleting all your migration files then running makemigrations -> migrate again

Comment: Np, please accept the answer if it helped, maybe it will help others also :)

Comment: Note. It's not recomment to delete migration files.